# How to set the horizontal white space after a section number in a section heading

Tags: spacing

The title says it all.  Of course, the same question applies to chapters, subsections, etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `titlesec` package for that. [Its documentation](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) specifies on p. 4 that using the `\titleformat` command can be used with the option `<sep>` giving the spacing you want to modify.